# Object reference not set to an instance of an object with class

Tags: c#, class

I have a situation where I have defined a class within a class, resembling the following:

```
    public partial class ProdData 
    {
    private string prodID;
    private string Description;

    ...and so on until I get to

    private ProdDataChildren[] childItemsField; 
    }
```

ProdDataChildren is it's own class, which I am using to identify sub-products that may belong to the parent product, hence the array.

In the main part of my program I have a loop that reads in records, sort of like:

```
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            ProdData ProductDataIn = new ProdData();
            ProductDataIn.ID = "values assigned here";
```

until I get to the point there I want to assign a child, this is where I am getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", using the following statement

```
         ProductDataIn.ChildItems[i].ProdID = "string variable here";
        }
```

I beleive the cause of the error is something to do with the current ChildItems being set to null, but how am I supposed to assign a value to it?  Do I need to instantiate and instance of the child item somehow and how would I do this?

Any help would be appreciated, I realize this might be a no brainer for some.

Comment: Just instantiate an array in the ProdData constructor.

Comment: Did you create an instance of the `ProdDataChildren` array?

Comment: What is `ChildItems`?

Comment: Brian -- I think this is where I went wrong.  I created an instance of ProdData, but not for the array.  Should I be doing this inside the class constructor or can I do it when I create an instance of ProdData?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to initialize your field before assigning anything to that collection. I would suggest using `List` instead of `Array`:

```
public partial class ProdData 
{

...and so on until I get to

private List<ProdDataChildren> childItemsField = new List<ProdDataChildren>(); 
}
```

With `List` you'll be able to do following:

```
ProductDataIn.ChildItems.Add(new ProdDataChildren() { ProdID = "string variable here" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You only declared the variable.  You didn't create a new instance of the array so you are trying to access an object that hasn't yet been created.